# Raven throws warnings when testing via Jest

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphql, jestjs

I'm trying to test my GraphQL api through Jest and every time I run my tests I keep getting this alert:

```
raven@2.5.0 alert: This looks like a browser environment; are you sure you don't want Raven.js for browser JavaScript?
```

**The cause:**

I create a custom `Error` class that inherits from `Error`:

```
import logError from './errors';

class LoggedErrorClass extends Error {
  constructor(error) {
    logError(error);
    const prototype = new.target.prototype;
    if (typeof error === 'string') {
      super(error);
    } else {
      super(error.message);
    }

    this.__proto__ = prototype;
  }
}

LoggedError = LoggedErrorClass;
```

And use it like this:

```
  if (!user || !Roles.userIsInRole(user._id, ['admin', 'customer'])) {
    throw new LoggedError('Access denied');
  }
```

`logError` is a function that uses `Raven`. Because I use Meteor I do `LoggedError = LoggedErrorClass` to make `LoggedError` accessible globally (notice, I don't export `LoggedErrorClass`)

My test looks like this:

```
import { graphql } from 'graphql';
import schema from '../../../graphql';

describe('getMobileSettings query', function() {
  // global.LoggedError = class extends Error {
  //   constructor(...args) {
  //     super(...args);
  //     Error.captureStackTrace(this, Error);
  //   }
  // };


  it('should work', async () => {
    const query = `
      query getMobileSettings($app: String!) {
        getMobileSettings(app: $app)
      }`;

    const [rootValue, context, params] = [{}, {}, { app: 'web' }];

    await graphql(schema, query, rootValue, context, params);
  });
});
```

I've tried setting `LoggedError` with the help of `global` but it didn't help. So, I can't just call `jest.mock('path/to/file')` because I don't export it. Also, it seems quite weird that `Raven` is here, because I use it in `logError` which I only import in a file where I create `LoggedErrorClass`

Comment: Jest by default creates a browser environment for your tests with JSDom. You can change this behaviour by setting `testEnvironment` to "node" [Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some digging, I figured out the solution. 
I decided not to mock `LoggedError` class but rather mock `logError` function that my class uses. As a result I came up with this code that mocks `Raven` behaviour:

```
const Raven = {};
const install = jest.fn();
const config = jest.fn();

Raven.install = install;
Raven.config = config;

// mocking chained function calls
install.mockImplementation((...args) => {
  return Raven;
});
config.mockImplementation((...args) => {
  return Raven;
});

export default Raven;
```

I've also updated my `jest.conf.js` by adding `raven` to `moduleNameMapper`:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^meteor/(.*)': '<rootDir>/tests/.mocks/meteor/index.js',
    raven: '<rootDir>/tests/.mocks/npm/raven.js',
  },
  automock: false,
  clearMocks: true,
};
```